# Input method behavior for EditText on GoogleMap

Tags: android, google-maps

My app consists of a single ActionBarActivity that shows a GoogleMap with an EditText overlaid on top of it.  When I touch the EditText in portrait orientation, the soft keyboard covers the EditText.  Then when I dismiss the soft keyboard, there's a solid black bar where the activity's action bar should be, and the "my location" button is missing from the map.  (I would post screenshots, but I don't have enough reputation.)

Is something wrong with my layout XML?  I stripped it down to the bare minimum that demonstrates the problem:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <fragment class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/locationField"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:hint="@string/hint_location"
        android:ems="10" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

My device is running Android 2.3.6.

Comment: Earn reputation by answering a question and get your answer upvoted or accepted ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are issues reported on gmails-api-issues, which are related to (probably, missing screenshots) your:

- http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4639
- http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4659

Basically it is solved for Android 4.1 and nothing will be done to fix it for lower versions of Android.

You may want to change your layout for API < 15 to contain `EditText` on a separate screen or something like that.

Comment: That does seem vaguely related, but not quite the same.  Other than the "my location" button, the map itself is rendering correctly; it's the action bar of the ActionBarActivity that becomes a black bar.  To summarize my issue another way, the window pans to expose the EditText, but doesn't pan far enough to actually expose it; and when it pans back, the action bar is not repainted.

For the time being, I have avoided the problem by adding `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize"` to the activity tag in the manifest.  But I consider this a workaround, not a solution.

Comment: @kjkrum The root cause will be the same. On devices with 4.0 and below `SurfaceView` is used behind the scenes. It doesn't like moving around and causes black holes in the universe. `TextureView` (used on 4.1+) is happy about being scrolled or animated in any way.